# Handling access violations from .NET

Tags: c#, exception, windbg

We run a program as a service and we attach adplus to it to get crash dumps.

On startup, we semi-regularly get crash dumps with a first chance access violation with the following call stack

```
0:011> !mk -cc
Thread 11:
           IP
00:M 00007ffa710ca358 PerformanceMonitor.GetData(String)(+0x19 IL,+0x88 Native)
01:M 00007ffa710c7c5f PerformanceCounterLib.GetPerformanceData(String)(+0xff Native)
02:M 00007ffa710c7e2c PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()(+0x35 IL,+0xac Native)
03:M 00007ffa710c771e PerformanceCounterLib.GetCategorySample(String, String)(+0xe IL,+0x4e Native)
04:M 00007ffa710b605f PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances(String, String)(+0x11 IL,+0x8f Native)
05:M 00007ffa165c4ef1 PerformanceCounterCollection.AddCounter(String, String)(+0xad IL,+0x241 Native)
06:M 00007ffa165c4a9f MonitorResponder.CreatePerformanceCounters()(+0x30 IL,+0x8f Native)
07:M 00007ffa165c47ac MonitorResponder.Start()(+0xa IL,+0x2c Native)
08:M 00007ffa718b39a5 ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)(+0x72 IL,+0x285 Native)
09:M 00007ffa718b3719 ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)(+0x0 IL,+0x9 Native)
0a:M 00007ffa718b36f7 ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext, ContextCallback, Object)(+0x57 Native)
0b:M 00007ffa718cadc1 ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()(+0x51 Native)
0c:U 00007ffa75b7a7f3 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
0d:U 00007ffa75b7a6de clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
0e:U 00007ffa75b7ae76 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x251
0f:U 00007ffa75d2969d clr!ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker+0x105
10:U 00007ffa75b7c121 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x2d
11:U 00007ffa75b7c0a8 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
12:U 00007ffa75b7c019 clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75
13:U 00007ffa75b7c15f clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+0x2f
14:U 00007ffa75d2957e clr!ThreadNative::KickOffThread+0xd2
15:U 00007ffa75cbfcb6 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
16:U 00007ffa7e4a13d2 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
17:U 00007ffa80b45454 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

I believe our dump actually comes from:

```
     foreach ( string instanceName in category.GetInstanceNames() )
```

WinDbg gives this line number and when I decompiled it showed that it calls GetCounterInstances.

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the list of performance object instances that are associated with this category.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// An array of strings representing the performance object instance names that are associated with this category or, if the category contains only one performance object instance, a single-entry array that contains an empty string ("").
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException">The <see cref="P:System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.CategoryName"/> property is null. The property might not have been set. -or-The category does not have an associated instance.</exception><exception cref="T:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception">A call to an underlying system API failed. </exception><exception cref="T:System.UnauthorizedAccessException">Code that is executing without administrative privileges attempted to read a performance counter.</exception><filterpriority>2</filterpriority><PermissionSet><IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/><IPermission class="System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Flags="UnmanagedCode"/><IPermission class="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterPermission, System, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" version="1" Unrestricted="true"/></PermissionSet>
public string[] GetInstanceNames()
{
  if (this.categoryName == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString("CategoryNameNotSet"));
  return PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances(this.categoryName, this.machineName);
}
```

From here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.getinstancenames(v=vs.100).aspx

I see that this method throws InvalidOperationException, Win32Exception, UnauthorizedAccessException.

Our c# code doesn't seem to have any exception handling in this area.

I'm wondering:
If we did try to catch InvalidOperationException, Win32Exception, and UnauthorizedAccessException would we still get a crash dump with a first chance access violation?

Can an access violation from a call to PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCounterInstances be handled?

I'm a little fuzzy on whether access violations can be handled successfully.  In this case we are calling out to .NET libraries for PerformanceCounters - so it is not like we can modify this code to prevent the access violation from happening.

We don't get this crash very often, but often enough that I recognize the callstack.

**Edit:**

We do run with legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true"

With our QA Servers – we run with full dump and exit on first chance access violations.

I believe our reasoning with this is that we don’t want to run with a corrupted process, and we want to get as much information as possible as soon as we get an access violation.

It could be nested deep inside a c++ call stack, but we could have a managed exception handler at the entry point.

We don’t want do a full dump and continue because sometimes you can get into a bad state and end up with tons of crash dumps.  Also, a full dump can take a long time, which I think can cause other problems.

By default customers don't run with adplus attached, but if they do, they run with minidump and continue on first-chance access violations.  For us, we always run with full dumps on first-chance access violations because we get better information out of them.

I guess our dilemma is that we want a full dump on first-chance if we have an access violation inside our c++ code but not necessarily when we are calling into .NET code and getting an access violation that we “handle”.  Although it is said that you can’t “handle” access violations.

I have seen several crash dumps on qa servers for server startup around PerformanceMonitor.  I checked and we do actually catch exceptions around this.  The problem is that when we have adplus attached to do full dump and exit on first chance access violations I end up with these crash dumps.

I guess I can probably ignore them, since they are likely handled safely when we don't had adplus set to do full dumps and exits on first-chance access violations.

```
0:011> .exr -1
ExceptionAddress: 00007ffa710ca358 (System_ni+0x000000000093a358)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 0000000000000000
Attempt to read from address 0000000000000000
```

Comment: This - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx (see Remarks section) answers your question. Access violation is corrupted state exception, and you can catch that if you want, but not by default.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Performance counter access is controlled by ACLs. If I'm using them, I usually wrap the first access with any catch (Exception is fine) and just don't touch them again if it throws.

Comment: You get crash dumps but the program continues successfully? Or does it actually crash?

Comment: Your post does not give evidence that you caught an access violation. What is the output of `.exr -1` and `!pe`?

Comment: Also, `GetInstanceNames()` is not on the call stack of `!mk`. What exactly makes you believe you're inside that method? The line number is only relevant if your symbols really match. Note that the line number in the PDB should be correct, but your source code file might have changed in the meanwhile.

Comment: The filename is: FULLDUMP_FirstChance_av_AccessViolation ...

Comment: Why do you care about *first chance* exceptions? They might be caught and the program simply works as expected. Later you talk about a *crash*, which contradicts the term *first chance exception* .

Comment: I have source code that matches the binaries that were build - getting a specific changeset from TFS.  The line number points to GetInstanceNames, which I decompiled and noticed calls GetCounterInstances.  I'm not sure why the callstack is missing this.

Comment: Good point Thomas, I have to be more careful with terminology.  After where I typed "Edit:" in bold you can see details of how we are running.  I think I just have to ignore crash dumps with this call stack.

Comment: The `.exr -1` output looks like a .NET `NullReferenceException` that was mapped to an `Access Violation`, which might happen sometimes, as described by [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/08/09/10440495.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *catch* access violation exception, by marking your method (method in which you have try catch block to catch exception in question) with [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) , or with configuration

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And if you are on .NET Frameowork 3.5-, they will be caught by default. However, even if you can *catch* it does not mean you can *handle* it. Such exceptions are called corrupted state exceptions for a reason - your process state might be corrupted in unpredictable ways, and so continue running in such state might lead your to unpredictable results. So you can catch it to log it, and gracefully exit - don't continue to run your application in this state.

So, to really solve your problem, you should find the reason of access violation exception and get rid of it, not "handle" it in catch block.

Answer (score 1):

A first-chance access violation does not necessarily mean a corrupted state.

A first-chance exception is just that - a first chance. In windows SEH exceptions, the SEH filter function has the opportunity to fix the problem and resume from the faulting instruction. Only if that fails, does the real exception occur, and the `__catch` handler executed.

(Aside:  The analogy for SEH would be a `SEGV` handler in Linux/unix. `__try` maps to setjmp, the exception maps to the handler. In the handler you can attempt to resolve the underlying issue and continue, or call `longjmp`, which in this analogy would transfer control to a conditional which jumped to the `__catch` block)

First chance exceptions are normal facility in windows, e.g. when loading up delay-load functions. The standard code path simply sets the handler, then jumps to the function address, which is initially zero. The access violation triggers an SEH handler which loads the import table with the function's address, then retries the call.

Provided there are no **unhandled** access violations, you probably don't need to worry about it. (The exception is if you have stability problems or otherwise suspect that such exceptions are not being handled correctly).